# Where are the TITAN Containers?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I am having a problem finding the titan containers in the subway tunnel and world tower.

When I go to subway station there is no place to get into the subway tunnel. What route do I need to take to get the titan containers in the subway tunnel and world tower?

Comment: Have you completed the game storyline?

Comment: The TITAN container mission cannot be completed the moment you get it. You have to progress a little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

To get in the **subway tunnels** you will have at least to be on the **mission where you are destroying penguin's disruptors**.When you get to the lower level o subway station you will see those 2 big tunnels from the map.Just following this mission will lead you straight to the first titan container and leave you near the entrance to the wonder tower.

In this video you can see the uploader having trouble getting to the lower level,probably same with you.At the end of the video you can also notice the first container blinking.

---

For the titan container in **wonder tower** you will have to be on the **mission where you are following the Ra's-al-guls assassin**.Following this mission will also lead you straight to the container.The doors to the wonder city are at the northern end of the central station(the big room at the eastern end of the tunnels).

Comment: Are these missable? If I didn't destroy them during the mission, can I not complete this side mission?

Comment: You can return to this area later on when it is unlocked and complete it.